# Custom filter in order grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, filter, order-grid

I'm trying to add a new field to order grid with custom filter. Right now I managed to make it work, but I want to add my custom filtering rule.

I added the column to db_schema.xml and in my module's sales_order_grid.xml file I added:

```
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="custom_field">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <options class="My\Module\Component\Listing\Columns\CustomFieldOptions" />
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Custom Field</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

In my CustomFieldOptions class I have:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace My\Module\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class CustomFieldOptions implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private const VALUE = 'value';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private const LABEL = 'label';

    /**
     * Return array of options as value-label pairs
     *
     * @return array Format: array(array('value' => '<value>', 'label' => '<label>'), ...)
     */
    public function toOptionArray() :array
    {
        return [
            [
                self::VALUE => 1,
                self::LABEL => 'Realized'
            ],
            [
                self::VALUE => 0,
                self::LABEL => 'Outdated'
            ],
            [
                self::VALUE => -1,
                self::LABEL => 'Canceled'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

My `custom_field` is DateTime, but I want to filter it using those 3 CustomFieldOptions parameters:

[image: Custom field in order grid with filter]

I want to specify my own filtering rule (for example option `Canceled` should filter only records with `null` value of my `custom_field`, `Outdated` should return records with `custom_field` value that's older than current day).

Can you help me with what should I do now? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get any further with the custom filtering rule on sales_order_grid. Driving me a bit mad

Comment: @elfling Thank you for reminding me to post my solution. Check my answer below and give me feedback if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see how I get on with that. I'm hoping that I can set condition to be in and also nin and use arrays. Much appreciate you getting back to an old thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to handle that problem with around plugin:

```
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\Select">
        <plugin name="my_module_order_grid_apply_filter_to_my_column" type="My\Module\Plugin\ApplyFilterPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
```

And here's a code snippet of that plugin:

```
/**
     * @param Select   $subject
     * @param callable $callback
     * @param array    $params
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function aroundPrepare(Select $subject, callable $callback, ...$params): void
    {
        if ($subject->getName() !== 'my_column') {
            $callback(...$params);

            return;
        }

        $filterParams = $subject->getContext()->getFiltersParams();

        if (!isset($filterParams[$subject->getName()])) {
            $callback(...$params);

            return;
        }

        $value = (int)$filterParams[$subject->getName()];

        $shippingToFilter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('shipping_to');

        switch ($value) {
            case 1:
                $shippingToFilter->setConditionType('notnull');
                break;
            case 0:
                $shippingToFilter->setConditionType('null');
                break;
            case -1:
                $shippingToFilter->setValue($this->timezone->date(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $shippingToFilter->setConditionType('lt');
                break;
        }
        $subject->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addFilter($shippingToFilter->create());

}
```